# WebSocket STOMP already override class principal method getname() convertAndSendToUser doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I just want to test if `convertAndSendToUser` is working or not. If you have the same problem or experience please help me to fix it.

You can see the method when I use the code upder it it same to ok（`convertAndSend`). When I use `convertAndSendToUser` my html can not get the STOMP message. So I guess destination is right，but something wrong I can‘t found;

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Resource
    private WebSocketHandshakeInterceptor webSocketHandshakeInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketService webSocketService;

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint(PathConstant.STOMP_CHAT_CHANNEL).addInterceptors(webSocketHandshakeInterceptor).setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();        registry.addEndpoint(PathConstant.STOMP_CLASS_COMMEND).setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS().setInterceptors(webSocketHandshakeInterceptor);

        // test
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS().setInterceptors(webSocketHandshakeInterceptor);
    }


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker(PathConstant.TOPIC, PathConstant.USER);
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(PathConstant.APP);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {

        registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
                if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {

                    String token = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Auth_token");

                    String username = webSocketService.checkToken(token).getUser_name();
                    String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");

                    SocketUser user = new SocketUser(uid,username);

                    accessor.setUser(user);

                    webSocketService.addSocketCache(uid, user);
                }
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
}
public class SocketUser implements Principal, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2882674220040446492L;

    private final String username;

    private final String userId;

    public SocketUser(String userId,String username) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }



    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return userId;
    }

}

@RestController
public class ChatroomController {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChatroomController.class);

@Autowired
private MessageService messageService;

@Autowired
private Gson gson;

@Autowired
ChatroomMessageRepository chatroomMessageRepository;

@Autowired
ChatroomUserRepository chatroomUserRepository;

@Autowired
private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

//    @Autowired
//    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

@Autowired
private SimpUserRegistry userRegistry;

@Autowired
WebSocketService webSocketService;

@MessageMapping(PathConstant.STOMP_CHAT_ADD_USER)
@SendTo(PathConstant.TOPIC_PUBLIC)
public ChatMessage addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage, StompHeaderAccessor accessor) {
    userRegistry.getUsers().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    accessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
    chatMessage.setUid(accessor.getUser().getName());
    return chatMessage;
}

@MessageMapping(PathConstant.STOMP_CHAT_ADD_MESSAGE)
@SendTo(PathConstant.TOPIC_PUBLIC)
public ChatMessage addMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage, StompHeaderAccessor accessor) {
    return chatMessage;
}

@MessageMapping(PathConstant.USER_CHAT)
public void sendToUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage, StompHeaderAccessor accessor) {
    String uid = accessor.getUser().getName();
    chatMessage.setType(ChatMessage.MessageType.CHAT);
    System.out.println("/user/" + uid + "/chat");
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(uid, "/user/" + uid + "/chat", chatMessage);
//        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + uid + "/chat" , chatMessage);
}
}
```

Comment: first time to use ，I paste code on it ，how can I paint the color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

super.convertAndSend(this.destinationPrefix + user + destination, payload, headers, postProcessor);
private String destinationPrefix = "/user/";
spring-message already put your uid and "user" in your destination , so you can use like this " messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(uid, "/chat" , chatMessage)"

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble following your post but the way I do it in my rest controllers is like so:

```
   @ApiOperation(
        value = "Returns the current SDDF Host/Port the bridge is connected to",
        produces = "application/json",
        notes =
        """
# STOMP Enabled
To access this endpoint via a **STOMP** websocket
* Send a message to: `/app/rest/sddf_info`
* Subscribe to: `/user/queue/rest/sddf_info`
    """
    )
    @GetMapping("/sddf_info")
    @MessageMapping("/rest/sddf_info")
    @SendToUser
    fun getSDDFInfo(): SDDFInfo {
        return SDDFInfo(
            sddfConfigProperties.hostName,
            sddfConfigProperties.hostPort
        )
    }
```

You can hit this controller 2 ways:

- http get to `/sddf_info`
- Sending a STOMP message to `/app/rest/sddf_info`

If you subscribe to `/user/queue/rest/sddf_info` the `@SendToUser` will deliver the response from the stomp incoming message to `/app/rest/sddf_info` to that topic

I have a configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class STOMPWebSocketConfig : WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

....

   override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue")
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user")
    }
```

That configures some of these endpoints locations..

(also this code is Kotlin not Java - but Kotlin is 100% java compatible ... so if you are writing java you should be able to figure it out from here)

Is this what your are asking ... how to use the user queue (`@SendToUser`) correctly?

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-websockets-sendtouser
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination